# Google App script (Make protected buttons)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I draw the buttons in google sheet and i want to make it protected so any user can't change the buttons layout and assign script/edit/delete.

Is it possible?

Comment: Your only options are to not grant edit access to the user or to protect the sheet where the button is located. If you provide more context about your situation, maybe a workaround could be found.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you may need to go to the [sharing access](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop), as to my knowledge the API does not provide the options to manage these rights for particular drawings. I assume you are using drawings to create a  button.